# How can I change the default Production file save location in Camtasia Studio?

Tags: screen-casting

When producing a video, Camtasia lets you pick the save location for the produced file but I can't find an option to change the location for this. I have set the *recording* and *temp* directories through other menus, but Camtasia asks for this location each time I produce and I have to manually change it each time.

The default location is `/users/documents/camtasia studio/` but I'd like to dump them into a different directory for ease of access.

Is there any way at all to change this location? If it matters I'm testing Camtasia Studio 8, but I've always had the same problem in Camtasia 7, and will be going back to Camtasia 7 if I don't like 8 enough to purchase it.

Answer (score 1):

In camtasia, if you choose a certain location that it will store it in your used places. Then you can access it easily through the dropdown list. Here is an image:
[image]

It isn't possible to change the default output folder though....

Comment: Ah, good to know! Not quite as good as setting the default, but a lot easier than fiddling with the directory picker each time

Comment: Hm doesn't seem to work in Camtasia 8 actually. The dropdown is there but never populates.

Comment: [This link](http://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/how_to_put_camtasia_studio_folder_in_another_location?from_gsfn=true) appears to say that the production folder is not configurable.

Comment: Crap, I'll just make a Junction point to lead that default folder to the location I want it then...

Comment: Just wanted to say @BenBrocka, that I installed the trial Camtasia Studio 8, and that it populated the dropdown list, and the last location produced at was the selected one the next time.

Comment: Really? Is it on the same drive? Did you type out the path or use the directory picker?

Comment: I used the directory picker.

Comment: Neither is working here. Always starts in the My Documents/camtasia studio...

Comment: Edited my answer to show an image from Camtasia 8.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug.  When you specify the folder, make sure you select the post-production option, "Show production results".  If you don't, it won't remember the last folder location.  I'm using 8.0.4 and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1 minute video on how to do this. It took me a while to find it as well so I thought it would be easier to show it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom production preset when you are selecting your video settings. I noticed that when I did this it also includes the output save location.